# Are "what is going to happen (in the future)?" like questions good fit for this site?

Tags: discussion

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173177/are-universal-apps-going-to-replace-wpf) question a good fit for SO?

I find it interesting, but it seems to me that any possible answer will be opinion based.

Are questions that ask about the future of a technology a  good fit? But I guess arguably there could be an answer saying something like (in this case) Microsoft has plans to replace WPF in 2016, or such.

Comment: No.  But they will be in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already attracted a ton of opinionated responses, so that should really give you your answer.

There are certainly questions that, while technically capable of objectively correct answers, in practice only ever attract opinions and speculation.  Almost all questions directed at the designers of a language fall into such a category.  *Technically* the designers can give an objective answer about their plans, in practice such questions just involve people guess what the designer's plans are.

Clearly this question *is* attracting primarily opinion based content, and I see every indication that it will only continue to do so, so it should be closed.

Comment: Yes I saw the answers were opinion based, but as you said someone could actually give a good answer. So In cases like this you would act accordingly the content the question has attracted? Or since it is almost impossible it could get a good answer, you would proceed to close it.

Comment: @Dzyann The hit/miss ratio is so great that we generally close these questions and if there are sufficient arguments on meta for keeping them re-open, we'll re-open them. In this case; it should be closed.

Comment: @Dzyann As George says, these types of questions, in practice, don't attract good answers, so it's best just to close them right away unless there's particularly compelling evidence that the case is different (i.e. a public announcement by the designers stating unequivocally what the answer is).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker and Servy - Thanks for the insights, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't flagging when it was a good question, since it really is a gray area. This will be useful for future reference also.